# Is there a way to match a string that also has numbers using Regex.IsMatch only?

Tags: c#, regex, match

I want to know if there's a regex expression to evaluate a string formatted like this: "XXYYYY" where XX is any letter and YYYY is any number.

I use this code to acomplish that, though I'm sure there's a better way without using Substring and only Regex.IsMatch.
Thanks!

```
 if (Regex.IsMatch(ValueString.Substring(0, 2), @"^[a-zA-ZñÑ\s]+$"))
 {
   if (int.TryParse(ValueString.Substring(2, 4), out value))
   {
   return true;
   }
 }
```

Comment: Is "  1234" a valid string? Because in question you said that XX can be any letter, but your regex allows spaces instead of letters

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single regex to test for exactly 2 letters and 4 digits:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(ValueString, "^[a-zA-ZñÑ\s]{2}[\d]{4}$");
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add quantifiers and a pattern for the numbers to your existing pattern:

```
return Regex.IsMatch(ValueString, @"^[a-zA-ZñÑ]{2}[0-9]{4}$");
```

`{2}` means "exactly 2 of the preceding expression". Using `[0-9]` rather than `\d` limits the range of numbers matched to latin decimal digits (`\d+` would include digits from other alphabets as well)

Answer (score 1):

You could test it with this `^\p{L}{2}\p{Nd}{4}$`

Explained

```
 ^             # BOS
 \p{L}{2}      # Two letters
 \p{Nd}{4}     # Four number digits
 $             # EOS
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution:

```
  string[] data =
  {
    "AB1234", // True
    "XA3456", // True
    "3d34hg", // False
    " .1234", // False
    "ñÑ1234", // True
    "ôà1234", // True 
  };

  foreach (bool result in data.Select(s => Regex.IsMatch(s, @"^[^\d\s\W]{2}\d{4}$")))
  {
    Console.WriteLine(result);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Pattern : ^\w{2}\d{4}$
Match groups:
1.  df5455
```

https://rubular.com/r/031g7m7uTE5MvU

Comment: This is matching `123456` or `_12345` but not `ñÑ1234`